# Removing Listview Jumping

Tags: c#, listview

I have a `ListView` which I am constantly adding items in.

I am able to scroll while the items in the `ListView` were being added.

However, upon selecting an item in the `ListView`, I am unable to scroll while items are being added. For each ListView.Items.Add(Object) I call, I will revert to the focus of the item initially selected.

Clearing the SelectedItems and SelectedIndices, I am still able to continue scrolling down the `ListView` as I keep popping back to the originally selected item anytime an item is added.

Could anyone advise how to get past this problem?

Thank you.

Regards,
Michael

Comment: If you select an item or items, the listview is not scrolling. right?

Comment: Once an item is selected, it doesn't. And trying to scroll would always kick me back to the item selected once an .Add() is called.

Comment: It is not clear.. post the code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using WPF, are you using an `ObservableCollection`? It sounds like the DataContext is being changed causing the ListView to reload. If you bind to an `ObservableCollection` you may have more luck.